# Is the quotient map on a locally compact topological group closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, $H$ a closed subgroup, $G/H$ the space of left cosets with the quotient topology, and $q:G\rightarrow G/H$ the projection map.  Also, let $C(G,\mathbb{C})$ be the space of continuous functions from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$.  The author of a book I am reading is attempting to define a subspace of $C(G,\mathbb{C})$ using (among others) the condition "$q($supp$(f))$ is compact".  Here is my problem: unless $q$ is a closed map I do not see how this condition can respect linearity (i.e., if $q($supp$(f))$ and $q($supp$(g))$ are compact then so is $q($supp$(f+g))$ for $f,g$ in this subspace).  If $G$ is simply a topological group and $H$ is compact, then it is true that $q$ is closed.  But in particular for locally compact groups can we say that $q$ is closed?  My belief is that this is not true, but I could be wrong.  Since the other conditions imposed on this "subspace" don't seem to help the matter, this would appear to be an error in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, $q$ may not be closed.  For instance, if $G=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}$ then you could have a closed subset of $G$ that contains points on infinitely many of the cosets of $\mathbb{R}$ which when projected down to $G/H\cong\mathbb{R}$ accumulate somewhere and thus the image is not closed. Presumably the intended condition is for $q(\operatorname{supp}(f))$ to be *precompact* (i.e. its closure is compact), rather than compact.  (Or, perhaps the *additional* assumptions being made which you have not mentioned are used in order to conclude that $q(\operatorname{supp}(f+g))$ will be compact.)

Comment: Thank you, it did not occur to me that taking the closure could save linearity.  (The other condition is that $f(x\xi)=\sigma(\xi^{-1})[f(x)]$ for $x\in G$, $\xi \in H$ where $\sigma$ is a unitary representation on $H$ and $f$ is really a continuous map from $G$ to the Hilbert space corresponding to $\sigma$.)

Comment: To make Eric's counterexample more specific for future readers: $(1/n, n)_{n\ge 1}\subset G$ is closed, but its projection on $G/H$ is $(1/n)_{n\ge 1}$. Not closed.