# Induced representations: question about proof in Folland's book

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

Consider the following fragment from Folland's book "A course in abstract harmonic analysis":

> **6.1 The Inducing Construction**
>
> Let $G$ be a locally compact group, $H$ a closed subgroup, $q : G \to G / H$ the canonical quotient map, and $\sigma$ a unitary representation of $H$ on $\mathcal{H}_\sigma$. We denote the norm and inner product on $\mathcal{H}_\sigma$ by $\lVert u \rVert_\sigma$ and $\langle u,v \rangle_\sigma$, and we denote by $C \left ( G, \mathcal{H}_\sigma \right )$ the space of continuous functiosn from $G$ to $\mathcal{H}_\sigma$.
> If $f \in C \left ( G, \mathcal{H}_\sigma \right )$, we shall frequently wish to apply the operators $\sigma(\xi)$ to the values $f(x)$, and to avoid clutter we shall usually write $\sigma(\xi)f(x)$ instead of the more precise $\sigma(\xi)[f(x)]$.
>
> The main ingredient in the inducing construction is the following space of vector-valued functions:
>
> $$\mathcal{F}_0 = \left \{ f \in C \left ( G, \mathcal{H}_\sigma \right ) \ : \ \text{$q \left ( \text{supp } f \right )$ is compact and $f(x \xi) = \sigma(\xi^{-1})f(x)$ for $x \in G$, $\xi \in H$} \right \}.$$
>
> Here is how to produce functiosn in $\mathcal{F}_0$:
>
> **6.1 Proposition.** *If $\alpha : G \to \mathcal{H}_\sigma$ is continuous with compact support, then the function*
>
> $$f_\alpha(x) = \int_H \sigma(\eta) \alpha(x \eta) \ d \eta$$
>
> *belongs to $\mathcal{F}_0$ and is left uniformly continuous on $G$. Moreover, every element of $\mathcal{F}_0$ is of the form $f_\alpha$ for some $\alpha \in C_c \left ( G, \mathcal{H}_\sigma \right )$.*
>
> Proof:
>
> Clearly $\boxed{q(\text{supp } f_\alpha) \subset q(\text{supp } \alpha)}$, and ...

How can we conclude that $q(\operatorname{supp}(f_\alpha))$ is compact from the boxed inclusion? I know that $q(\operatorname{supp}(\alpha))$ is compact, so it suffices to show that the former set is closed. But I don't see why this is true.

Any help/comments/insight is highly appreciated!

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that future users have an easier time finding this question. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: Also, you're right to worry. $\text{supp }(f_\alpha)$ is closed by definition. But $q$ is not a closed map in general (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4140079/is-the-quotient-map-on-a-locally-compact-topological-group-closed), for instance), so $q(\text{supp }(f_\alpha))$ may not be closed! Are you sure the author isn't considering the closure of $q(\text{supp }(f_\alpha)$?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor No I'm not sure, which is why I ask the question ^^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks for the edit btw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed false that the image of closed subset of $G$ under the quotient map $q$ is closed in $G/H$.

However,  here we are dealing with a special closed set. Let $A = \operatorname{supp}(f_\alpha)$. By (left) invariance of the (left) Haar measure, we see that $f_\alpha(x)= 0 \iff f_\alpha(xh) = 0$ for all $h \in H$. In particular, we thus have that $AH\subseteq A$.

Now, invoke the following general fact:

**Lemma:** If $q: G \to G/H$ is the quotient map and if $A \subseteq G$ is a closed subset such that $AH \subseteq A$, then $q(A)$ is closed in $G/H$.

**Proof**: Since $q$ is an open map, it suffices to show that $q(A^c) = q(A)^c$. The inclusion $q(A^c)\subseteq q(A)^c$ follows from the condition $AH\subseteq A$ (exercise!) while the other inclusion follows from surjectivity of $q$. The lemma follows. $\quad \square$